# Returning value and updating row without "interference" in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have this stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spGrabSerial
  @serial nvarchar(16) output
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  set @serial = (SELECT top 1 serial from tblSerial)
  update tblSerial set InUse = 1 where serial = @serial
END
```

How can I make sure that no other procedure grabs the same serial in between the select and the update?

Comment: Don't forget to check that the serial isn't in use: `SELECT top 1 serial from tblSerial where InUse <> 1`

Comment: Hehe. I just saw it myself, minor detail ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming SQL Server 2005+ you can use the `OUTPUT` clause to do it in one atomic operation (see [Using tables as Queues](http://rusanu.com/2010/03/26/using-tables-as-queues/)).

```
 ;with cte as (
    select top(1) 
      serial, InUse
    from tblSerial with (rowlock, readpast)
    where InUse <> 1
    order by serial
   )
 update cte 
 set InUse = 1 
 output inserted.serial
```

**Edit** Just been reminded of a way of doing this that can assign directly to the `output` parameter without using the `OUTPUT` clause at all.

```
 with cte as (
    select top(1) 
      serial, InUse
    from tblSerial with (rowlock, readpast)
    where InUse <> 1
    order by serial
   )
 update cte 
 set InUse = 1, @serial = serial
```

Comment: Nice. How do I stuff the inserted.serial into the @serial output-variable? I thought SP's could only return numeric values?

Comment: If you need to assign it to an `OUTPUT` variable and can't just use it as is then you need to `OUTPUT INTO @tablevariable` then assign from that. There is no syntax to assign to a scalar variable directly from `OUTPUT` for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you run it in transaction isolation level 'Repeatable Read':

```
set transaction isolation level repeatable read
```

Then run the stored procedure in a transaction, and it'll be isolated from other changes.